# how to store data to redis using php

Tags: php, redis

I have a php form to upload data and need to store uploaded data such as images, texts, .. in redis, but i'm wondering if it's a good idea to change uploaded data to binary and store it as a value in redis then for displaying that data, restore from binary.

thanks

Comment: Why would you ever store images in Redis?

Comment: storing images in a database is almost **NEVER** a good idea. there are very few usage cases where it make sense and a LOT of cases where it's just downright stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Redis to store JSON object or user messages. Read about redis more.
Yuu can store path of images, but not binary code.

The most useful short book about Redis is: [openmymind.net/redis.pdf](http://openmymind.net/redis.pdf) It very helped me. And else source to read is official documentation: [redis.io/documentation](http://redis.io/documentation)

Comment: if you provide a link to Redis, or other data, it'll be more helpful for the author.

Comment: If you need help about how create data model at Redis, ask me